# Log4j not showing logs when spark job is submited on yarn cluster

Tags: apache-spark, jar, log4j2

No application logs are shown in the yarn logs when a job is submit on yarn cluster. Everything works on local mode.

The following error is shown:

```
StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation
```

I provide following to the spark-submit:

```
--driver-library-path /opt/spark-extras/apache-log4j-2.11.2-bin \
    --conf spark.driver.extraLibraryPath=/opt/spark-extras/apache-log4j-2.11.2-bin \
    --conf spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/opt/spark-extras/apache-log4j-2.11.2-bin \
```

The `spark-defaults.conf` specifies the log4j2.xml:

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions ...  -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Then my log on yarn shows only something like:

```
2019-06-05 16:45:28,495 [main] WARN  org.apache.spark.SparkConf - The configuration key 'spark.executor.port' has been deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0 and may be removed in the future. Not used anymore
2019-06-05 16:45:46,298 [Driver] WARN  org.apache.spark.SparkConf - The configuration key 'spark.executor.port' has been deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0 and may be removed in the future. Not used anymore
2019-06-05 16:45:46,314 [Driver] WARN  org.apache.spark.SparkConf - The configuration key 'spark.executor.port' has been deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0 and may be removed in the future. Not used anymore
2019-06-05 16:45:46,315 [Driver] WARN  org.apache.spark.SparkConf - The configuration key 'spark.executor.port' has been deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0 and may be removed in the future. Not used anymore
2019-06-05 16:45:48,324 [Driver] WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.FairSchedulableBuilder - Fair Scheduler configuration file not found so jobs will be scheduled in FIFO order. To use fair scheduling, configure pools in fairscheduler.xml or set spark.scheduler.allocation.file to a file that contains the configuration.
2019-06-05 16:45:49,977 [Reporter] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl - Received new token for : 
2019-06-05 16:45:50,654 [ContainerLauncher-2] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy - yarn.client.max-cached-nodemanagers-proxies : 0
2019-06-05 16:45:53,692 [Reporter] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl - Received new token for :
```

How can I configure that spark-submit job to make it log using log4j2 as it works on local mode?

Comment: what is deploy-mode is it cluster or client

Comment: `--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster`

Comment: try to send log4j config to executor using --files since its cluster mode it expects the log4j to be present in every node

Comment: Done that, didn't help. I think the log4j jar is not in the classpath on the nodes:
`    --files "${ML_PATH}/config/application.conf,${ML_PATH}/config/log4j2.xml" \
    --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath="-Dconfig.file=file:application.conf -Dconfig.file=file:log4j2.xml"\
    --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:log4j2.xml \
    --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:log4j2.xml`